# Windows PowerShell does not display colors

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

Instead of colored text, when I run a command, I get something like this:
`[32mqueue:restart[39m` . It worked fine, then I decided to change the font of the PowerShell, and after a PC reboot, I no longer see color. Can someone aid me in fixing this? I tried changing back the font, and resetting all the settings of the PowerShell, but that didn't help.

Comment: What powershell host are you using? ISE? ConsoleHost?

Comment: I just use it, as you would use Windows CMD. I navigate with it, and use it with my Laravel5 install, to make controllers and such. I don't quite understand your question

Comment: Does `Write-Host "foo" -ForegroundColor Green` output anything with color?

Comment: Yes, this returns a green foo

Comment: Looks like whatever program you are running in powershell, breaks the color output of powershell.

Comment: But the funny thing is, all worked well before I changed the Font.. oh well, guess I'll just use Bash. Thanks for the help